# What happens if you do not specify the version of the maven plugin?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

What will happen if spring boot 2 in pom.xml does not indicate the version of the plugin. Will it automatically use the latest version? For example maven-surefire-plugin.

```
<build>
        <!--Закомментировать если сборка с Java-->
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <!---->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From maven 3.x [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-AutomaticPluginVersionResolution)

> When a plugin was invoked without an explicit version given in the POM
>   or on the command line, Maven 2.x used to pick the latest version
>   available where the latest version could either be a release or a
>   snapshot. For the sake of stability, Maven 3.x prefers the latest
>   release version over the latest snapshot version.
>
> Given the threat of non-reproducible builds imposed by automatic
>   plugin version resolution, this feature is scheduled for removal as
>   far as plugin declarations in the POM are concerned. Users of Maven
>   3.x will find it output a warning when missing plugin versions are detected to encourage the addition of plugin versions to the POM or
>   one of its parent POMs. The Enforcer rule requirePluginVersions can be
>   used additionally check for missing plugin versions in the POM.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends what your parent is. Spring Boot's parent has `pluginManagement` for a number of plugins (including surefire) so it will use that version. This is a fixed version and it depends on the Spring Boot version you're using.

There is no guarantee that it will be the latest, even if you use the latest Spring Boot version as we try to be consistent with our upgrade policy. You can figure this out yourself via `mvn help:effective-pom`.